# How can I make my WCF Client encrypt the SOAP Body of my request?

Tags: .net, soap, wcf-client, ws-security, public-key-encryption

How can I sign and encrypt my WCF clients service call (from spec: All messages shall be signed and encrypted corresponding to WS-Security X.509 Token Profile. The specification can be found [here](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/16785/wss-v1.1-specos-%20x509TokenProfile.pdf)).

I must use SOAP 1.1 and WS-Security, the service is provided by a 3rd party and I am pretty sure they wrote it using Java (IBM DataPower) (not WCf anyway).

I have tried the following, but I think it is the case of asking the wrong question as most of what I have read says that the client won't decide what is encrypted and that this is defined by the services protection level (SignAndEncrypt). I've also seen references to an X509SecurityToken that I should use to encrypt, however I think this is older .net.

Anyway this is what I have so far:

```
' Create the binding.
Dim myBinding As New BasicHttpBinding() ' FOR SOAP 1.1
myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential
myBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate
myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate

' Create the endpoint address. 
Dim ea As New EndpointAddress("https://removed")

' Create the client. 
Dim starClientProxy As New wcfStarServiceProxy.starTransportPortTypesClient(myBinding, ea)

' Specify a certificate to use for authenticating the client.
starClientProxy.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "removed")

'Cert used for encryption
starClientProxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.AddressBook, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "removed")
```

so now it should just encrypt it automatically? I can't find anything that I need to set

```
'call the service    
Dim response As wcfStarServiceProxy.AcknowledgeRepairOrderPayload = starClientProxy.ProcessMessage(payload)
```

So, I think I have succeeded in signing the request, however, the body isn't encrypted. How can I encrypt the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dejan led me to an answer:

```
Private Function GetCustomBinding2() As Channels.Binding

    Dim httpsBindingElement As New HttpsTransportBindingElement()
    httpsBindingElement.AllowCookies = False
    httpsBindingElement.BypassProxyOnLocal = False
    httpsBindingElement.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard
    httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288
    httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = 65536
    httpsBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536
    httpsBindingElement.RequireClientCertificate = True
    httpsBindingElement.UseDefaultWebProxy = True



    Dim asbe As New Channels.AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement
    asbe.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11
    asbe.InitiatorTokenParameters = New ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters
    asbe.RecipientTokenParameters = New ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters
    asbe.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict
    asbe.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Sha256
    asbe.IncludeTimestamp = True
    asbe.SetKeyDerivation(False)
    'asbe.OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody = True

    'asbe.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(New ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters)
    'asbe.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SetKeyDerivation(False)

    Dim myBinding As New CustomBinding

    myBinding.Elements.Add(asbe)

    myBinding.Elements.Add(New TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    'myBinding3.Elements.Add(New HttpsTransportBindingElement())
    myBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement)



    Return myBinding
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a custom binding to implement 2 levels of security - certificate AND username-password. I did it like this (code excerpt):

```
        CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding();
        // ...
        HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        httpsBindingElement.AllowCookies = false;
        httpsBindingElement.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        httpsBindingElement.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferPoolSize = 20480000;
        httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = 20480000;
        httpsBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20480000;
        httpsBindingElement.RequireClientCertificate = true;
        httpsBindingElement.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        TransportSecurityBindingElement transportSecurityElement = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
        transportSecurityElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());
        transportSecurityElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SetKeyDerivation(false);
        // ...
        customBinding.Elements.Add(transportSecurityElement);
        customBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);
```

This way the message is signed and encrypted by the client using the username and password, however you can modify this example and accomplish what you require.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. I need to use X509SecurityTokenParameters as I am using certificates, not username password. I used this binding, but the SOAP body is still not encrypted.

Comment: @MrShoubs instead of `TransportSecurityBindingElement` try `AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement` and post back

Comment: Do you know of any good articles on this? I'm not sure what I am after. Now I have a message: AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement cannot build a channel or listener factory. The InitiatorTokenParameters property is required but not set. I'm not sure how to set it.

Comment: @MrShoubs sorry, I haven't read any good article on this - I usually do trials-and-errors. In the light of that, can you try the following: `SecurityBindingElement transportSecurityElement = AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement();`

Comment: Yes, this is trial and error for me as well as I don't really know what I am expected to use, or how to find out, and that linked spec in my question doesn't help :(... Do people generally not sure this kind of security?